# Best Way to Bring Commits from Master Back to Staging

Tags: git, git-flow

We accidentally put a bunch of new commits directly into our Master branch, and now we need to bring them back into Staging. What is the best way to do this to prevent git issues?

Here's our flow (notice how we typically go from feature branches to Staging, then Master):

Feature Branches -> Staging -> Master -> Deploy

Comment: You could reset staging to master, but obviously you will need to re-merge anything that was in staging but not yet in master, would that work?

Comment: We have a script which basically does `git reset --hard origin/master` but also looks for open PRs with `staged` label and try to merge them. We identify branches which are merged in staging but not yet in master by assuming they will have open PR with such label.

Comment: `What is the best way to do this to prevent git issues?` What kind of issues are you concerned about?

Comment: just `git reset --hard sha` on master and  `git push -f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the local copy of master.

Go to staging branch:

```
git checkout staging
```

Rebase it on top of master (which includes the changes you want):

```
git rebase master
```

Or, instaed of rebase master, you can use:

```
git cherry-pick <commit-sha1>
```

For each commit you want to bring from master into staging branch

Comment: great solution, thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can simply reset staging to master:

```
git checkout staging
git reset --hard origin/master
git push --force
```

This will make staging identical to master. The problems that you could encounter with this approach is that any feature branches merged to staging, but not yet in master, will need to be re-merged in staging again.

If you have other considerations, let us know in the comments happy to re-think my answer then.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without losing all the commits in staging?

Comment: @Rob You can simply cherry-pick the range of commits to staging. You can also merge master to staging.